# Как отправить сообщение всем пользователям бота Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Вроде бы легкая задача, но в API не нашел подобного, либо плохо искал. 
python (pyTelegramBotApi)

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю так, просим написать пользователей чтонить в бота (или выполнить /start), далее делаем get запрос:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{ваш ключ}/getUpdates
```

Там список последний сообщений и ID chat, их и подставляем в sendMessage

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны хранить на своей стороне id всех чатов, когда-либо инициированных пользователями с вашим ботом. Тогда Вы сможете отправить сообщения по всем имеющимся id, то есть всем пользователям.
В **[документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sendmessage)** эти параметры являются обязательными:
[image: Telegram Bot API]
Получить эти данные с серверов телеграмма нет возможности.

Comment: не всем, а только тем, кто ещё не удалил бота

Comment: @Anatol, всё равно отправлять нужно абсолютно всем - просто для пользователь тех кто удалил чат и забанил бота вернется ошибка 403.  При этом, лучше не убирать таких пользователей из списка после этого, а продолжать отправлять сообщения им, т.к. они могут разбанить бота потом, и в этом случае сообщения ему приходить не будут, даже если он это захочет.

Answer (score 1):

Выход только один, хранить `id` всех кто когда либо писал вашему боту, например в базе данных, и в следствии отправлять каждому сообщение.

В случае с ботами `user_id == chat_id`.

При рассылке нужно учитывать лимиты Telegram Bot API:

> When sending messages inside a particular chat, avoid sending more
>   than one message per second. We may allow short bursts that go over
>   this limit, but eventually you'll begin receiving 429 errors.
>
> If you're sending bulk notifications to multiple users, the API will
>   not allow more than 30 messages per second or so. Consider spreading
>   out notifications over large intervals of 8—12 hours for best results.
>
> Also note that your bot will not be able to send more than 20 messages
>   per minute to the same group.

Судя по документации Telegram Bot API, возможно в будущем будет добавлена возможность делать рассылку:

> Unfortunately, at this moment we don't have methods for sending bulk
>   messages, e.g. notifications. We may add something along these lines
>   in the future.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял, нельзя так делать. Необходимо узнать id разговора и только на него можно отправлять сообщения. Например, так это можно сделать с помощью `flask`:

```
@app.route('/api/send_message/', methods=['POST'])
def send_message_by_id():
    json_string = request.json
    id = json_string['id']
    message = json_string['message']
    bot.send_message(str(id), message)
    return 'ok'
```

Вот так можно сделать, чтобы бот по запросу `get id` отдавал `id` разговора:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def info_message(message):
    msg = message.text.lower()
    # Если запрос идет из группового чата, то в сообщении будет присутствовать имя бота
    if message.chat.type == 'group':
        msg = ' '.join(msg.split(" ")[1:])
    if msg == 'get id':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.chat.id)
```

Comment: `func` в вашей реализации не влияет ни на что, `content_types` по стандарту установлен в `text`. Проверять тип чата и полученное сообщение лучше прямо в хендлере с помощью `func`.
В случае с командами, следует задавать `commands` в хендлер, а не проверять их как текст, команды не могут разделятся пробелом, что делает `join` бесполезным, если команда вызвана с ником бота, и есть хендлер который отвечает за обработку данной команды, команда будет принята как с ником бота так и без него. И хочу заметить что этот ответ никак не решает проблему автора с рассылкой.

Comment: @Alban а вы сообщение перед кодом и дату публикации смотрели?

Comment: Не понимаю о чем вы. Как это влияет на ответ?